# php password generating function

Tags: php, function, random

Here is a question i want to solve

> "Write a function GeneratePassword which accepts two arguments, an integer and a character string consisting of letters (a-z) and digits (0-9).
>
> When GeneratePassword(5,'abc0123') is called, it should return a random string of 5 characters taken from 'abc0123'.
>
> For Example : GeneratePassword(7,'abczxc012394') could return any of the following outputs : 
>   2c00acb 
>   2c23z93 
>   030b2a4
>   "

I have written the following code for it, but the system says that the answer is wrong. Please explain what am i doing wrong.

My code :

```
    function GeneratePassword($digits,$passwordString){
    if($digits > strlen($passwordString)) return '';
    else {
        $randomSelect = '';
        for($i=0;$i<$digits;$i++){
            $randomChar = $passwordString[rand(0, strlen($passwordString)-1)];
            $randomSelect = $randomSelect.$randomChar ;
            $passwordString = str_replace($randomChar,"",$passwordString);

        }
        return $randomSelect;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the wrong answer. Is it that you're getting an error message?

Comment: Just verifying, you can use each character just once right? I mean, for you to have something twice, it must be present twice in the source string, right?

Comment: appears to be working: http://codepad.org/jbjZuMsd

Comment: the system says? can you explain better your problem? the function is correct and the output is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't reject `$digits` being higher than the number of characters to choose from. You could easily receive `GeneratePassword(10,'A')`, in which case you'd need to return `AAAAAAAAAA`.

Second, you shouldn't remove selected characters from the string. The examples even include duplicate characters (`2c00acb` for instance).

Apart from that, your code seems to work. I would suggest, though, that you calculate `strlen($passwordString)` up front and save it in a variable, rather than computing it once for every iteration of the loop.

Comment: The below code is doing the same in the function

    if($digits > strlen($passwordString)) return '';

Comment: @backTangent, did you even read his answer? It's right on the mark.

Comment: @BenLee yes i read it. What did i say wrong. I just said that he is write, only one line is involved in it, and i can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

```
function GeneratePassword($length,$characters) {

    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
echo GeneratePassword(7, 'abczxc012394');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the version I would make. Mind you that I've replaced "$digits" with "$length", because, well, that's what it's supposed to indicate. Also, I've replaced "$passwordString" with the more commonly accepted term "$seed". Explanation is inline.

```
function GeneratePassword( $length, $seed ) {
    $password = ''; /** Begin with an empty string. */
    $max = ( $length - 1 ); /** Calculate the number of characters in seed -1, because strings are zero-indexed. */
    for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++ ) { /** Loop until the maximum length is reached. */
        $password .= $seed[mt_rand( 0, $max )]; /** Select a random character and append it to the password string. */
    }
    return $password; /** return the password */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function GeneratePassword($digits,$passwordString){

    $randomSelect = '';
    for($i=0;$i<$digits;$i++){
        $randomChar = $passwordString[rand(0, strlen($passwordString)-1)];
        $randomSelect = $randomSelect.$randomChar ;
        $passwordString = str_replace($randomChar,"",$passwordString);

    }
    return $randomSelect;

}
```

you should reuse the chars in $passwordString

Answer (score 0):

```
function GeneratePassword($n,$c){
  $pw = '';
  for ($l = 0; $l < $n; $l++){
    $r = rand(0, strlen($c) - 1);
    $pw .= $c[$r];
  }
  return $pw;
}
```